# Get data from table B in not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys im working on a problem. i have 2 tables, table a contains a list of users table b contains a list of their "clock ins", at the moment im selecting distinct dates from table b and then for each date, im checking if the user has checked in for that date. BUT what i want to be able to do is select some data from the Table B as well .. but when i try i just get spammed with all the data from table B. here is my statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A,
     Table B
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Table B
              WHERE Table B.user_id = Table A.id 
                And Table B.date = 'given date here')
```

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Please post a syntactically correct query.

Comment: has been updated by zerkms.

Comment: Try selecting the column names that you want instead of the *, and you might not need the exist at all, it might just be a simple join.

Comment: well the real purpose is to turn this into a not exist statement, i just left not exist out by accident, what my aim is is to check for people who are absent on a day.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why you want to select data that is not there, but if you still have to, then I would take your schema as-

```
USER
-----------------
user_id
username
...
...


USER_CLOCKIN
-----------------
user_id
clockin_datetime
...
...
```

I would query this as-

```
SELECT u.*, uc.*
  FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN user_clockin uc
       ON u.user_id = uc.user_id
 WHERE uc.user_id IS NULL
;
```

This selects all the columns from both the tables. Modify your `SELECT` list as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try running following:

```
SELECT table_a.name,table_b.date FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id=table_b.id WHERE table_b.date=<xx.yy.zzzz>
```

of course replace xx.yy.zzzz with date wanted. also, visit  http://www.mysql.org go to documentation, and find more info on join, left join and right join...